# Javascript jQuery Hide Form Items Based on Select Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a form in which when someone selects "Other" as their title, they get a box appear to input the title. The first part of my script works in order to make the div hidden to begin with but I can't quite get the second part to work in which selecting "Other" makes a text box appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
            <div>
                <label for="title" class="label">Title</label>
                <select name="title" id="title">
                <option></option>
                <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
                <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="miss">Miss.</option>
                <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
                <option value="dr">Dr.</option>
                <option value="lady">Lady.</option>
                <option value="rev">Rev.</option>
                <option value="sir">Sir.</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input name="other_title" style="margin-left:10px;" type="text" id="other_title" size="10">
            </div>
```

Here is my Javascript/jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function( $ ) {
        $('#other_title').hide('fast');
        $(function() {
            if ($('#title option:selected').text() == 'other') {
                $('#other_title').show('fast');
            }
        }); // end function
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing the event handler.

Comment: Is that to tell the function to actually run? By that I mean have I set it up but not told it what should trigger it off?

Comment: it is sort of action triggered when you press a button, check a checkbox/radio, focusing the textbox, etc., [**EVENTS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).   Within you can write things to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be of any help?

```
$('#title').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'other') $('#other_title').show('fast');
    else $('#other_title').hide('fast'); // This too?
});
```

**Edit**: Fixed syntax error. :p

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. The only error is that it needs the ")" after the brace. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Try using change event and replacing

```
if ($('#title option:selected').text() == 'other')
```

with

```
if ($('#title>option:selected').text() == 'other')
```

You can refer the plunkr for reference:
https://plnkr.co/edit/R2w25NEwUbiw00r2lEs3